# Chunked Reactjs widget: which script to import in my page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, code-splitting, dynamic-import

I am trying to **serve a React widget** for a Chatbot messenger like Intercom widget. Everything works fine until the SEO team argues with me about the size of the downloaded script.

I'm using:

```
React 16.13.1
React-scripts 3.4.1
Typescript 3.9.6
Redux 4.0.5 
Styled-components 5.1.1 
Material-UI 4.11.0
...
```

It weighs ~570k (gzipped) and that **costs around 25 points on Google lighthouse** benchmark.

So, just like Intercom did when [they face the same issue](https://www.intercom.com/blog/reducing-intercom-messenger-bundle-size/), **I split my code into chunks** using dynamic `import()` feature. Now, when I run the benchmark it gives a good mark (I gain ~15 points) and **everything goes green** on dev mode.

But, I'm not sure anymore:

- how to integrate my widget's chunks on customer's pages? (of course not as they are in dev mode: 5 separate script tags)
- Which chunk/script from the generated ones should I use, and which one come dynamically?
- do chunks really call each other only when needed? (because they don't look so!)
- Do orders make a difference? (JS so I think it does)

I used to integrate similar script before modification:

```
<script
   src="cdn.myhost.com/script.min.js"
   data-lang="en"
   data-license="XXX-XXX"
   data-options='{"tags":["test"]}'
/>
```

Any suggestions will be helpful!